# How to hide Bootstrap 3 Modal on clicking button within it and re-open it on clicking a button on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="">ADD New User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="addMsg"></div>
              <form method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="location" class="control-label">Location:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="disLocation">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" >ADD</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

The button opens the modal:

```
<button class="addNew btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addData">ADD New</button>
```

It works well , it shows up on clicking ADD New button and disappears on clicking close button , when I x or outside the modal.

I'm using it to insert data to Database and I want it to be hidden on clicking the button with `class="add"` within the modal body , and then if I click ADD New button again it shows up.

I tried :

```
 //On Clicking The Button Within Modal Body To Insert Data To Database.
    $( "#add" ).on('click', function(){
        $('#addData').removeClass('fade in');
        $('#addData').addClass('fade');
        $('#addData').hide();
        $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('fade in');
        $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('fade');
        $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    });


//On Clicking The ADD New Button To Show The Modal Again To Insert Another User.
$( ".addNew" ).on('click', function(){
    $('#addData').removeClass('fade');
    $('#addData').addClass('fade in');
    $('#addData').show();
    $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('fade');
    $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('fade in');
    $('.modal-backdrop').show();
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});
```

But it's not working because I have to click on ADD New button twice after the modal is hidden , I think that's because it's conflicting with Bootstrap functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".add").click(function(){
    $("#add").click();
});
```